# cmus hiding artist songs

Tags: debian, cmus

I'm using `cmus` with Debian Buster. In the artists list (view 1), I see a single `Al Green`, with a single song. If I filter

```
:filter artist="Al Green"
```

I see Al Green repeated twice, first with the previously visible song (from the Pulp Fiction album), and second with his full album. However, when I remove the filter

```
:filter
```

then there's only one `Al Green` again, with a single song. What's happening here?

EDIT

I noticed that one Al Green is on A, and the other is on G (on alphabetical order). Elton John appears in both E and J, with different songs in each. Why?

Comment: it seems obvious ... the album name does not get returned when the filter is removed ... test it with other artists

Comment: @jsotola I see nothing obvious with it. Even before applying the filter, his full album wasn't there, when it should be. (...) After seeing other artists out of place, I noticed that one Al Green is on A, and the other is on G. Elton John appears in both E and J, with different songs in each. Why?

Comment: no idea ... i was only making a comment on a possible behavior .... contact the cmus development team and ask

Comment: @jsotola Contacted: https://github.com/cmus/cmus/issues/959

Comment: Can you compare the artist metadata tags of the two (artist, album artist etc.)